# Eclipse cannot find; Failed to find a main class eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErwhS.png)

Hello. I'm facing this error while running Eclipse. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Try doing a full clean & build of your project

Comment: I'm getting this error when I reinstall.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?